# Version number in custom module's module.xml and composer.json

Tags: magento2, module, versioning

Should the version number in custom module's **module.xml** and **composer.json** be the same?

module.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.5" />
</config>
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Company\/Mymodule",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.5",
```

In core modules I see their different, but I'm not sure what are the consequences.

Comment: Version in composer.json is not relevant: [Optional if the package repository can infer the version from somewhere, such as the VCS tag name in the VCS repository. In that case it is also recommended to omit it.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version)

Answer (score 0):

They probably should match, but they don't have to.

The module.xml number is used for Magento setup and upgrade script versioning. If that number increases, you have to run the setup process, and Magento will execute the Setup/Upgrade* scripts during that.

The composer.json number is for dependency checking during composer updates. Magento doesn't look at this number directly (for the most part).